# Finding the cause of of 403 forbidden error in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have multiple users in django auth setup and a few simple models.
For superusers I can view my model objects. For non superusers that have is_staff checked I get
a 403 Permission denied when trying to view my models.

I have tried adding all permissions to those users to find out if that was the cause but still receive the forbidden message. Other than making them superusers I can't assign any more permissions.

On the command line where I'm running the development server I see messages like
"GET /admin/bcp/buildingsensor/24/ HTTP/1.1" 403 190614

Does anyone know how to get a more useful traceback for this so I know where to start looking. ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Also, what do you mean 'view my models'? Are the users trying to view the models through the built in admin, or through a view?

Answer (score 7):

In the end, I add debug and traceback directly into the Django source.
I manage to trace it back to:

```
if not self.has_change_permission(request, obj):
   raise PermissionDenied
```

This reminded me I had overridden `has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None)` in my model.

Comment: Had same problem with `def has_perm` in `User` class, on a project I didn't know much about the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox (or any browser) with Web Developer Toolbar, make sure you have cookies enabled. I temporarily had cookies turned off and forgot to turn it back on.

`Cookies => Disable Cookies => Disable All Cookies`

Solved my problem in Django 1.9.